# Angular 2: Error while accessing JSON from HTTP

Tags: json, angular, angular-services, angular-http

I am creating an application in angular 2. I am trying to access the json data via http in a service. But i am getting an error saying that

```
**GET http://localhost:4200/data/products.json 404 (Not Found)**
```

I have the data in the specified folder but i am unable to access it.

My service code is as follows.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Item } from './item';

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
observableItems: Observable<Item[]>
allItems: Item[] = [];
selectedItems: Item[] = [];
errorMessage: string;
url = "http://localhost:4200/data/products.json";
constructor(private http:Http) { 
   this.observableItems = this.http.get(this.url).map((res: Response) => res.json());
   this.observableItems.subscribe(
             data => this.allItems = data,
         error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
   return this.observableItems;
}
getSelectedItems(): Item[] {
   return this.selectedItems;
}   
    addItem(id:number): void {
       let item = this.allItems.find(ob => ob.id === id);
       if (this.selectedItems.indexOf(item) < 0) {     
      this.selectedItems.push(item);
   }
    }
    removeItem(id:number): void {
   let item = this.selectedItems.find(ob => ob.id === id);
   let itemIndex = this.selectedItems.indexOf(item);
       this.selectedItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You probably want to access an endpoint serving data in JSON format. An address `http://localhost:4200/data/products.json` suggests that there is a document `product.json` available for download. You are more likely to query `http://localhost:4200/data/products`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My html files are in

```
"Project/src/app/..."
```

So to access JSON File I need to come back from tabs folder and app folder to reach the base directory for both code and images. I used ../ to come back from a folder.

From this my url in the service will be as follows:

```
url = "../../assets/data/products.json";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using direct path to the file from the location of your service file. For example:

```
url = "data/products.json";
```

It will work.

Comment: can you please tell me the path of your file relevant to the service? It should work.

Comment: i tried changing the path of the file into the src.. the path is url="./assets/data/data.json"

Comment: can you share the screenshot of your folder structure where i can see the service and assets folder?

Comment: Have attached the screenshot. have a look into it

Comment: Ok the path you should use is "../assets/data/data.json". Try and let me know if it resolves the issue.

Comment: I tried every possible thing with the path.. I think the problem is not with the url.

Comment: just try this for the last time "../assets/data/products.json". And can you paste some data from your json file?